# Unrecognized VM option '+UseCompressedOops' when running kafka from my ubuntu in vmware

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I am working with ubuntu using VMware
I have Installed hadoop single node cluster in it.
Then I have installed zookeeper and had run the zookeeper.
then when I run my "Apache kafka" it throws an error.

**Unrecognized VM option '+UseCompressedOops'**

**Could not create the Java virtual machine**

single@ubuntu:~/yoga/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin$ **./zkServer.sh start**

JMX enabled by default

Using config: /home/single/yoga/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg

Starting **zookeeper ... STARTED**

single@ubuntu:~/yoga/kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0$ **bin/kafka-server-start.sh  config/server.properties**

Unrecognized VM option '+UseCompressedOops'

**Could not create the Java virtual machine.**

Answer (score 13):

Since your VM doesn't support '+UseCompressedOops' option. To fix it, remove that option from the kafka's configuration which'll help you to start the both (zookeeper & kafka) servers.

1) Go to the Kafka installation directory :

```
cd kafka_2.8.0-0.8
```

2) Edit the Kafka's classpath setter script :

```
vi bin/kafka-run-class.sh
```

3) Search for "KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS" token & remove '-XX:+UseCompressedOops' from that line.

i.e., before removing :

```
KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

with after removing :

```
KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

4) Start your both zookeeper & kafka server instance

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Comment: +1 The same problem was showing in my windows machine too. Removing UseCompressedOops did solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Removing UseCompressedOops from kafka-run-class.bat solve did solve the problem on Windows for me, too

Comment: Removing this option is not the case. I had the same problem with Zulu JVM. So you should consider another JVM vendor.

Answer (score 4):

This actually depends on the `VM` mode you are running with .. there are 2 types 
1) Server side 
2) Client side

`+UseCompressedOops` is recognized by the server VM and probably that's the reason why you are getting this error.. there could be multiple ways to check under which mode the `VM` is currently running, but the easiest one I could find is to simply run `java -version` and it should print some thing like this

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

there are few nice discussion regarding these two flavors of VM. You can take a look at @VonC 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client) regarding the basic differnece between these two.

more discussions here
[What does the UseCompressedOops JVM flag do and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054548/what-does-the-usecompressedoops-jvm-flag-do-and-when-should-i-use-it)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit machine? 
I have faced similar error and i resolved it by doing following steps:

1) download kafka ( in my case kafka-0.7.2-incubating-src)

2) extract it

3) cd to kafka home(where you extract the tgz)

/home/kuntal/Kuntal/BIG_DATA/kafka-0.7.2-incubating-src

4) run

./sbt update
./sbt package

5) now cd to kafaka home bin

/home/kuntal/Kuntal/BIG_DATA/kafka-0.7.2-incubating-src/bin

6) type

kafka-server-start.sh /home/kuntal/Kuntal/BIG_DATA/kafka-0.7.2-incubating-src/config/server.properties

you will see Kafka server started in terminal.Hope this help someone !! :)