# heap memory touches new high every time

Tags: java, heap-memory

[image: jconsole heap graph]

the peek in my graph is touching new high every time. 
my vm arguments as follows,

```
-XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

is it fine or something wrong with the arguements?

Comment: You might have some kind of memory leak.

Comment: When you press the button "Perform GC", the JVM runs a "stop the world" garbage collection. After this gc run, you will see the amount of memory that cannot be freed. If this amount increases over time (press "Perform GC" from time to time), it's likely that you have a memory leak.

Comment: Agreed with what others have already said here.  Just a minor suggestion: you can likely remove the `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`.  Modern JDK versions have compressed oops on by default.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054548/what-does-the-usecompressedoops-jvm-flag-do-and-when-should-i-use-it .

Answer (score 1):

This looks normal to me.

Objects are created in the Eden space and you appear to have about 400 MB of Eden. (The size between the peak and minimum memory usage)

This indicates you are creating about 3 of these every 3 hours or about 400 MB/hour.  Note: your monitoring tool could be creating a lot or even most of this garbage.

After each minor collection, surviving objects are added to the Survivor spaces.  Once these objects have been copied enough times they are added to the tenured space.

As you are using JMX / RMI, this could be both the main cause of garbage in the eden and retained objects. I suggest you reconnect and perform a full GC. This will let you know how much is actually being retained.

If the amount retained after a full GC is increasing, you might have a memory leak.